Frontend and backend connection problem of docker containerized web app
I am trying to use docker to containerize my web app(frontend: vite-react, backend:.net8, database: azure sqlserver).
I built dockerfiles for both frontend and backend, nginx.conf for frontend, and docker-compose.yml for the whole project.
Currently I can visit the frontend page at my designated port, but the frontend page cannot make successful request to backend. I can see information from network in chrome developer tool as following.
Request URL: http://backend:8081/api/Sceneries/Index
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

index-BRXy4mqk.js:196 Error fetching sceneries: 
xe {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

index-BRXy4mqk.js:193 
 GET http://backend:8081/api/Sceneries/Index net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Below are my codes and my debug trying:
1.dockerfile for frontend
FROM node:latest AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dnsutils

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

2.nginx.conf for frontend
events {}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;

        # Location block for serving frontend static files
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    }
}


.env.production file in my frontend folder

VITE_API_URL = http:/backend:8081/api

4.dockerfile for backend
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 As base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY Backend.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore Backend.csproj

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet build Backend.csproj -c Release -o /app/build


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Backend.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Backend.dll"]


docker-compose.yml for the whole project

version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./Frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - VITE_API_URL=http://backend:8081/api
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - app-network

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./Backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8081
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081
      - ConnectionStrings__ApplicationDbContext=Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=60;
    networks:
      - app-network
    
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: msa_project-network


I tried following ways to figure out the problem:

check the connection between frontend and backend containers by running these commands and get successful feedbacks.
I can get data from database by the curl command.

docker-compose exec frontend /bin/sh nslookup backend

curl http://backend:8081/api/Sceneries/Index

because these 2 commands are successful, I think there is no problem with my backend settings.

change the VITE_API_URL from: 'http://backend:8081/api' to 'http://(real backend container ip):8081/api' in .env.production file(not the one in docker-compose.yml, modify that one never works), but it does not solve the problem, the frontend page send failed request as following:

index-CxVmYAce.js:196 Error fetching sceneries: 
xe {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

index-CxVmYAce.js:193 
 GET http://(real backend container ip):8081/api/Sceneries/Index net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

So far I have no idea how to do further check and fix this problem, could anyone help me to figure out it? Thank you in advance!

I solved the problem, the environment:

VITE_API_URL=https://backend:8082/api I set in docker-compose.yml is correct, but... VITE_API_URL = https://localhost:8082/api I set in my frontend file need to be localhost instead of backend! this makes everything well.

